# AWS SNS Subscription Payload-based Filter Policy filtering everything

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm trying to send notifications from SNS to my Email-JSON, but my filter policy is filtering all notifications.

Below is an example notification that I would like to receive (For readability, refer to the example below this one):

```
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "1ed9186e-6bc3-5fbd-a328-44e3cc6cdc89",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:704284871969:AWSConfig-ServiceNow",
  "Subject" : "[AWS Config:ap-southeast-2] AWS::EC2::Instance i-088657d3062d3a749 Discovered in Account 70428487...",
  "Message" : "{\"configurationItemDiff\":{\"changedProperties\":{},\"changeType\":\"CREATE\"},\"configurationItem\":{\"relatedEvents\":[],\"relationships\":[{\"resourceId\":\"eni-08c11cf9e7825b69d\",\"resourceName\":null,\"resourceType\":\"AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface\",\"name\":\"Contains NetworkInterface\"},{\"resourceId\":\"sg-0eb540c1cf74b4334\",\"resourceName\":null,\"resourceType\":\"AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup\",\"name\":\"Is associated with SecurityGroup\"},{\"resourceId\":\"subnet-15eaed72\",\"resourceName\":null,\"resourceType\":\"AWS::EC2::Subnet\",\"name\":\"Is contained in Subnet\"},{\"resourceId\":\"vol-05f94020ee0ddd10a\",\"resourceName\":null,\"resourceType\":\"AWS::EC2::Volume\",\"name\":\"Is attached to Volume\"},{\"resourceId\":\"vpc-31cf9056\",\"resourceName\":null,\"resourceType\":\"AWS::EC2::VPC\",\"name\":\"Is contained in Vpc\"}],\"configuration\":{\"amiLaunchIndex\":0,\"imageId\":\"ami-047dcdc46ac4f2e6b\",\"instanceId\":\"i-088657d3062d3a749\",\"instanceType\":\"t2.micro\",\"kernelId\":null,\"keyName\":\"AWS-ServiceNow Test KeyPair\",\"launchTime\":\"2023-03-16T23:25:23.000Z\",\"monitoring\":{\"state\":\"disabled\"},\"placement\":{\"availabilityZone\":\"ap-southeast-2a\",\"affinity\":null,\"groupName\":\"\",\"partitionNumber\":null,\"hostId\":null,\"tenancy\":\"default\",\"spreadDomain\":null,\"hostResourceGroupArn\":null},\"platform\":null,\"privateDnsName\":\"ip-172-31-15-82.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal\",\"privateIpAddress\":\"172.31.15.82\",\"productCodes\":[],\"publicDnsName\":\"ec2-3-104-223-227.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com\",\"publicIpAddress\":\"3.104.223.227\",\"ramdiskId\":null,\"state\":{\"code\":0,\"name\":\"pending\"},\"stateTransitionReason\":\"\",\"subnetId\":\"subnet-15eaed72\",\"vpcId\":\"vpc-31cf9056\",\"architecture\":\"x86_64\",\"blockDeviceMappings\":[{\"deviceName\":\"/dev/xvda\",\"ebs\":{\"attachTime\":\"2023-03-16T23:25:23.000Z\",\"deleteOnTermination\":true,\"status\":\"attaching\",\"volumeId\":\"vol-05f94020ee0ddd10a\"}}],\"clientToken\":\"b711a8f7-110c-4f47-bd72-9932d4313faa\",\"ebsOptimized\":false,\"enaSupport\":true,\"hypervisor\":\"xen\",\"iamInstanceProfile\":null,\"instanceLifecycle\":null,\"elasticGpuAssociations\":[],\"elasticInferenceAcceleratorAssociations\":[],\"networkInterfaces\":[{\"association\":{\"carrierIp\":null,\"ipOwnerId\":\"amazon\",\"publicDnsName\":\"ec2-3-104-223-227.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com\",\"publicIp\":\"3.104.223.227\"},\"attachment\":{\"attachTime\":\"2023-03-16T23:25:23.000Z\",\"attachmentId\":\"eni-attach-0f058795b16390fbc\",\"deleteOnTermination\":true,\"deviceIndex\":0,\"status\":\"attaching\",\"networkCardIndex\":0},\"description\":\"\",\"groups\":[{\"groupName\":\"launch-wizard-1\",\"groupId\":\"sg-0eb540c1cf74b4334\"}],\"ipv6Addresses\":[],\"macAddress\":\"02:47:69:aa:e6:fc\",\"networkInterfaceId\":\"eni-08c11cf9e7825b69d\",\"ownerId\":\"704284871969\",\"privateDnsName\":\"ip-172-31-15-82.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal\",\"privateIpAddress\":\"172.31.15.82\",\"privateIpAddresses\":[{\"association\":{\"carrierIp\":null,\"ipOwnerId\":\"amazon\",\"publicDnsName\":\"ec2-3-104-223-227.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com\",\"publicIp\":\"3.104.223.227\"},\"primary\":true,\"privateDnsName\":\"ip-172-31-15-82.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal\",\"privateIpAddress\":\"172.31.15.82\"}],\"sourceDestCheck\":true,\"status\":\"in-use\",\"subnetId\":\"subnet-15eaed72\",\"vpcId\":\"vpc-31cf9056\",\"interfaceType\":\"interface\"}],\"outpostArn\":null,\"rootDeviceName\":\"/dev/xvda\",\"rootDeviceType\":\"ebs\",\"securityGroups\":[{\"groupName\":\"launch-wizard-1\",\"groupId\":\"sg-0eb540c1cf74b4334\"}],\"sourceDestCheck\":true,\"spotInstanceRequestId\":null,\"sriovNetSupport\":null,\"stateReason\":null,\"tags\":[{\"key\":\"Name\",\"value\":\"AWS-ServiceNow Test Instance\"}],\"virtualizationType\":\"hvm\",\"cpuOptions\":{\"coreCount\":1,\"threadsPerCore\":1},\"capacityReservationId\":null,\"capacityReservationSpecification\":{\"capacityReservationPreference\":\"open\",\"capacityReservationTarget\":null},\"hibernationOptions\":{\"configured\":false},\"licenses\":[],\"metadataOptions\":{\"state\":\"pending\",\"httpTokens\":\"optional\",\"httpPutResponseHopLimit\":1,\"httpEndpoint\":\"enabled\"},\"enclaveOptions\":{\"enabled\":false},\"bootMode\":null},\"supplementaryConfiguration\":{},\"tags\":{\"Name\":\"AWS-ServiceNow Test Instance\"},\"configurationItemVersion\":\"1.3\",\"configurationItemCaptureTime\":\"2023-03-16T23:25:34.317Z\",\"configurationStateId\":1679009134317,\"awsAccountId\":\"704284871969\",\"configurationItemStatus\":\"ResourceDiscovered\",\"resourceType\":\"AWS::EC2::Instance\",\"resourceId\":\"i-088657d3062d3a749\",\"resourceName\":null,\"ARN\":\"arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:704284871969:instance/i-088657d3062d3a749\",\"awsRegion\":\"ap-southeast-2\",\"availabilityZone\":\"ap-southeast-2a\",\"configurationStateMd5Hash\":\"\",\"resourceCreationTime\":\"2023-03-16T23:25:23.000Z\"},\"notificationCreationTime\":\"2023-03-16T23:25:35.494Z\",\"messageType\":\"ConfigurationItemChangeNotification\",\"recordVersion\":\"1.3\"}",
  "Timestamp" : "2023-03-16T23:25:35.936Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "PPLMqBqGZu+KBp5++PsF1ydXh0neltzP3UayivU4mVh4qW7iDcpe+u0sXmN36kJdGKwYQJZ+mCncufllhfUChZVgai61Zo5x0y250I6Is79uyv0jvKpSTYlvLaC30WAAOXbdZVlbezhPF9wSBpqam0WzhyWm4A1DlXzE87on61v72jkXSM4n7OvNwGalB6NR1A7uniVvByA4w1f1Kmrob5Nfo1REpyB+3E1SkHYmNnS7P8p6cBUVeqBtXzPsBzmBlxSunFDA85rZKGSACphaMV/IN/YQDTi6W/WFE9U8SG3uaN8rvImgSKC1skUArXgP1Y0Q288gYx+Cj5t30eeT4Q==",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-56e67fcb41f6fec09b0196692625d385.pem",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:704284871969:AWSConfig-ServiceNow:7e01b5ac-b015-4b51-be91-de1dde896e7d"
}
```

Formatted Example

```
{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "1ed9186e-6bc3-5f...",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:7042--------:AWSConfig-ServiceNow",
  "Subject" : "[AWS Config:ap-southeast-2] AWS::EC2::Instance i-088657d3... Discovered in Account 7042.......",
  "Message": {
        "configurationItemDiff ": {
            "changedProperties ": {},
            "changeType ": "CREATE "
        },
        "configurationItem ": {
            "relatedEvents ": [],
            "relationships ": [
                {
                    "resourceId ": "eni-08c11cf9e... ",
                    "resourceName ": null,
                    "resourceType ": "AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface ",
                    "name ": "Contains NetworkInterface "
                },
                {
                    "resourceId ": "sg-0eb540c1... ",
                    "resourceName ": null,
                    "resourceType ": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup ",
                    "name ": "Is associated with SecurityGroup "
                },
                {
                    "resourceId ": "subnet-15e... ",
                    "resourceName ": null,
                    "resourceType ": "AWS::EC2::Subnet ",
                    "name ": "Is contained in Subnet "
                },
                {
                    "resourceId ": "vol-05f94... ",
                    "resourceName ": null,
                    "resourceType ": "AWS::EC2::Volume ",
                    "name ": "Is attached to Volume "
                },
                {
                    "resourceId ": "vpc-31cf9... ",
                    "resourceName ": null,
                    "resourceType ": "AWS::EC2::VPC ",
                    "name ": "Is contained in Vpc "
                }
            ],
            "configuration ": {
                "amiLaunchIndex ": 0,
                "imageId ": "ami-047dcdc4... ",
                "instanceId ": "i-088657d3062d... ",
                "kernelId ": null,
                "keyName ": "AWS-ServiceNow Test KeyPair ",
                "launchTime ": "2023-03-16T23:25:23.000Z ",
                "monitoring ": {
                    "state ": "disabled "
                },
                "placement ": {
                    "availabilityZone ": "ap-southeast-2a ",
                    "affinity ": null,
                    "groupName ": " ",
                    "partitionNumber ": null,
                    "hostId ": null,
                    "tenancy ": "default ",
                    "spreadDomain ": null,
                    "hostResourceGroupArn ": null
                },
                "platform ": null,
                "privateDnsName ": "ip-172....ap-southeast-2.compute.internal ",
                "privateIpAddress ": "172.... ",
                "productCodes ": [],
                "publicDnsName ": "ec2-3....ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com ",
                "publicIpAddress ": "3.... ",
                "ramdiskId ": null,
                "state ": {
                    "code ": 0,
                    "name ": "pending "
                },
                "stateTransitionReason ": " ",
                "subnetId ": "subnet-15e... ",
                "vpcId ": "vpc-31c... ",
                "architecture ": "x86_64 ",
                "blockDeviceMappings ": [
                    {
                        "deviceName ": "/dev/xvda ",
                        "ebs ": {
                            "attachTime ": "2023-03-16T23:25:23.000Z ",
                            "deleteOnTermination ": true,
                            "status ": "attaching ",
                            "volumeId ": "vol-05f94... "
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "clientToken ": "b711a8f7-1... ",
                "ebsOptimized ": false,
                "enaSupport ": true,
                "hypervisor ": "xen ",
                "iamInstanceProfile ": null,
                "instanceLifecycle ": null,
                "elasticGpuAssociations ": [],
                "elasticInferenceAcceleratorAssociations ": [],
                "networkInterfaces ": [
                    {
                        "association ": {
                            "carrierIp ": null,
                            "ipOwnerId ": "amazon ",
                            "publicDnsName ": "ec2-3....ap-southeast-                   2.compute.amazonaws.com ",
                            "publicIp ": "3.... "
                        },
                        "attachment ": {
                            "attachTime ": "2023-03-16T23:25:23.000Z ",
                            "attachmentId ": "eni-attach-0f0587... ",
                            "deleteOnTermination ": true,
                            "deviceIndex ": 0,
                            "status ": "attaching ",
                            "networkCardIndex ": 0
                        },
                        "description ": " ",
                        "groups ": [
                            {
                                "groupName ": "launch-wizard-1 ",
                                "groupId ": "sg-0eb540c1cf... "
                            }
                        ],
                        "ipv6Addresses ": [],
                        "macAddress ": "02:... ",
                        "networkInterfaceId ": "eni-08c11cf9e7... ",
                        "ownerId ": "7042-------- ",
                        "privateDnsName ": "ip-172....ap-southeast-2.compute.internal ",
                        "privateIpAddress ": "172.... ",
                        "privateIpAddresses ": [
                            {
                                "association ": {
                                    "carrierIp ": null,
                                    "ipOwnerId ": "amazon ",
                                    "publicDnsName ": "ec2-3....ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com ",
                                    "publicIp ": "3.... "
                                },
                                "primary ": true,
                                "privateDnsName ": "ip-172....ap-southeast-2.compute.internal   ",
                                "privateIpAddress ": "172... "
                            }
                        ],
                        "sourceDestCheck ": true,
                        "status ": "in-use ",
                        "subnetId ": "subnet-15ea... ",
                        "vpcId ": "vpc-31c... ",
                        "interfaceType ": "interface "
                    }
                ],
                "outpostArn ": null,
                "rootDeviceName ": "/dev/xvda ",
                "rootDeviceType ": "ebs ",
                "securityGroups ": [
                    {
                        "groupName ": "launch-wizard-1 ",
                        "groupId ": "sg-0eb540c1cf7... "
                    }
                ],
                "sourceDestCheck ": true,
                "spotInstanceRequestId ": null,
                "sriovNetSupport ": null,
                "stateReason ": null,
                "tags ": [
                    {
                        "key ": "Name ",
                        "value ": "AWS-ServiceNow Test Instance "
                    }
                ],
                "virtualizationType ": "hvm ",
                "cpuOptions ": {
                    "coreCount ": 1,
                    "threadsPerCore ": 1
                },
                "capacityReservationId ": null,
                "capacityReservationSpecification ": {
                    "capacityReservationPreference ": "open ",
                    "capacityReservationTarget ": null
                },
                "hibernationOptions ": {
                    "configured ": false
                },
                "licenses ": [],
                "metadataOptions ": {
                    "state ": "pending ",
                    "httpTokens ": "optional ",
                    "httpPutResponseHopLimit ": 1,
                    "httpEndpoint ": "enabled "
                },
                "enclaveOptions ": {
                    "enabled ": false
                },
                "bootMode ": null
            },
            "supplementaryConfiguration ": {},
            "tags ": {
                "Name ": "AWS-ServiceNow Test Instance "
            },
            "configurationItemVersion ": "1.3 ",
            "configurationItemCaptureTime ": "2023-03-16T23:25:34.317Z ",
            "configurationStateId ": 1679009134317,
            "awsAccountId ": "7042-------- ",
            "configurationItemStatus ": "ResourceDiscovered ",
            "resourceType ": "AWS::EC2::Instance ",
            "resourceId ": "i-088657d3... ",
            "resourceName ": null,
            "ARN ": "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:7042--------:instance/i-088657d3... ",
            "awsRegion ": "ap-southeast-2 ",
            "availabilityZone ": "ap-southeast-2a ",
            "configurationStateMd5Hash ": " ",
            "resourceCreationTime ": "2023-03-16T23:25:23.000Z "
        },
        "notificationCreationTime ": "2023-03-16T23:25:35.494Z ",
        "messageType ": "ConfigurationItemChangeNotification ",
        "recordVersion ": "1.3 "
   },
  "Timestamp" : "2023-03-16T23:25:35.936Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "PPLM...",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-56....pem",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:7042--------:AWSConfig-ServiceNow:7e01..."
}
```

Below is the Payload-based Filter Policy I'm implementing:

```
{
    "messageType ": [
      "ConfigurationItemChangeNotification "
    ],
    "configurationItem ": {
      "awsAccountId ": [
        "7042-------- "
      ],
      "resourceType ": [
        "AWS::EC2::Instance "
      ]
    }
}
```

**Note that:**

1. I've censored the `awsAccountId`, but it is definitely matching.
2. I've also tried with and without the whitespace at the end of each attribute/value.
3. I've tested without any filter and the messages are indeed being sent.
4. Using CloudWatch, I can see that the payload-based filter is filtering all published messages.
5. I've narrowed it down to just `messageType` or `configurationItem` filter and no result.
6. Changing the values of `messageType` or other attributes' value still filters everything
7. Replacing the whitespace with the original backslash outputted by AWS SNS does not work.

Comment: It is intriguing that there is a space before the closing bracket in all entries inside the `Message` (but not outside the message). Would you know whether this was caused by your editor, or perhaps by removing backslashes? Not sure if it's related, but it does look a bit strange. They certainly don't appear in [Example Configuration Item Change Notifications - AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/example-sns-notification.html).

Comment: If you try just **one** filter, does it behave correctly? For example, just filtering on the `messageType`? And then try filtering on `messageType` with a different value to see if it changes the behaviour. You might be able to narrow-down the problem this way.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It was originally backslashes which I replaced with whitespace for visibility. I have just went ahead and tried including the backslash but no luck.

I have narrow it down to just `messageType` filter and that did not work. I've also tried narrowing it down to `configurationItem` only and that did not work as well. Changing the values have no effect as nothing comes through.

Comment: It would be helpful if your question represented reality. The messages might be included as a string rather than normal JSON, hence the difficulty in getting the filter to work. I wonder if [Amazon SNS raw message delivery - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-large-payload-raw-message-delivery.html) would help?

Comment: Yep, you are right, the `messageBody` is actually wrapped in a String. And nope, unfortunately, enabling raw message does not get rid of the String. My actual goal is to send SNS messages to a ServiceNow instance using a HTTP/s endpoint.

I have just updated the description to include the unmodified payload.

Comment: @BenzChua Did you figure this out? I have the same problem. I've reduced my test down to a single string attribute and it's still getting filtered out.

Comment: Yes @omatase. Sorry I've been really caught up with a project. The solution for me was to maintain the structure. According to the payload, messageType is placed beneath configurationItem, therefore, I switched them and it worked. Make sure to remove the whitespaces. 

I tested and confirmed the selected EMAIL-JSON sends through when I start/stop my EC2 instance. Weird thing is it doesn't work even if you narrow the test down to a single attribute. Not entirely sure why but my colleague is looking into it for me.